# Display Json from two nodes with Ajax

Tags: ajax, json

I am having difficulty to display data from json. Title shows fine but ***item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.type*** returns undefined.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:isbn=0-13-727827-6',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
        $(".tab1").append("<div>" + item.volumeInfo.title + "</div><div>" + item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.type + "</div>");
    });
}
});
```

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HFs8U/1/

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put [0] before .type as a volumeInfo can have two industryIdentifiers.  Naturally this will only show the first one so you may need to find a more appropriate way of showing both if more than one exist.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:isbn=0-13-727827-6',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
            $(".tab1").append("<div>" + item.volumeInfo.title + "</div><div>" + item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].type + "</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: david99world would you suggest the solution to display a few instances?

Comment: I'd say do another $.each an loop through each item, really depends on what you want them displayed :)

Comment: can you please add $.each into my loop please on jsfiddle?

Comment: really sorry for being stupid, I don't know ajax and jquery well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I've not really got the time to write the query, you might get more joy from writing a new question asking how to iterate through a nested json object :)

Comment: It's something like...   $.each(item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, function (item) { then appending this.type but I couldn't work out the attribute name

Comment: Cheers david99world. I have amended your code and seems it is working now. Please see my answer below. Hope it can be useful for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions wasn't very difficult. david99world suggested to do another $.each an loop through each item and pointed to a fiddle. I have slightly amended it and came up with:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:isbn=0-13-727827-6',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        $(".tab1").append("<div>" + item.volumeInfo.title + "</div>");
        $.each(item.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, function (i2, type) {
            $(".tab1").append("<div>" + type.type + "</div>");
        });
    });
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8SnaL/

Hopefully it may be useful for some body else.